# Error when replacing Image in publisher file

Tags: c#, ms-office, publisher

I am trying to replace an image in a Publisher file with the following method:

> shape.PictureFormat.Replace("images/image.bmp");

The problem is i get an error on this code:
No image can be inserted in the publication. The correct graphical converter is not available.

I can't seem to figur out where this error is from.

Answer (score 0):

The error was the folder it tried to look at. I was sure it was the same but for some reason it wasn't. I changed it to a full path and it works.